# Python 3 - Regular expression for a set digit length?

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if another string matches with the following string:

`'abc_xxxxxxxxxxxxx.txt'`

e.g.

`abc_20170926121600.txt` would match

but

`xyz_20170926121600.txt` or `abc_201709261216002323232323232323.txt` would not match

Comment: Have you looked at `{}` for the repetition specifier in the re docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
abc_\d{N}\.txt
```

Where N is the number of digits.

Comment: Technically you would need to escape the period with a \ too, otherwise it would match any single charachter between the digits and the 'txt'.